Change/automate the pattern in a link with python or powershell
I need to export html file of a link like given below,
https://www.drishtiias.com/current-affairs-news-analysis-editorials/news-analysis/15-05-2024
Now, instead of downloading a new page every day. I want to automate it. So I made a script to download the links given in text file. But in the text file itself, I have to add the link.
Is there a way using python or powershell or any other better instrument by which I can  update the last part of the link as given above to current date. Ex: from 15-05-2024 to 16-05-2024 and further automatically.
Also how can I manually increase or decrease the date by certain days , if in case I might not be able to run my script daily.
Thanks
I ran the script using beautifulsoup.

Sure there is. Not very complicated in Powershell, as the [datetime] and [system.dateonly] object make managing and changing dates quite easy.
But we can only help you if you already have a script with a honest attempt, otherwise you need to pay a professional.

Welcome to SO, Alphage _. Please read the information at https://stackoverflow.com/help to lean how SO works. Please make special note of the need for the question to provide an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example). The MRE is the source code you are trying to make work.

Ultimately I found the best python library named Arrow, It's much easier than date time, and can provide custom format, increase or decrease the date by required days. Must see.

In powershell, you can use the Get-Date cmdlet.
Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy" # for todays date
# Output: 08-06-2024
Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(7) -Format "dd-MM-yyyy" # for 5 days from now
# Output: 15-06-2024

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date#example-3-get-the-date-and-time-with-a-net-format-specifier
In python, you can use the datetime library
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()
futureday = today + timedelta(days=7)

print(today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")) # Output: 08-06-2024
print(futureday.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")) # Output: 15-06-2024

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-module/#python-timedelta-class
